# How to run a simple TestNG class using terminal?

Tags: java, terminal, testng, command-line-interface

I want to run a simple TestNG class using terminal not after adding it in suite.xml

I want to invoke the eclipse operation **Right click -> Run As -> TestNG Test** using terminal/CLI.

Is there is any way to Do it?

```
public class FirstTest {
@Test()
public void test {
  System.out.println("Hello TesNG!");
}
```

How to compile and Run the above TestNG code using CLI?

Comment: There's no direct way to do this according to the [docs](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html) - you need to specify an xml suite in order to use the testNg CLI like

Answer (score 0):

There's no direct way to do this according to the [docs](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html) - you need to specify an xml suite in order to use the testNg CLI like `java org.testng.TestNG testng1.xml`

However, you can create some `main` method in your project and invoke `TestNg` programmatically: add necessary `Test` classes into suite and call this `main` method from CLI like any other Java application:

```
public static void main(String ... args){
    TestListenerAdapter tla = new TestListenerAdapter();
    TestNG testng = new TestNG();
    testng.setTestClasses(new Class[] { FirstTest.class });
    testng.addListener(tla);
    testng.run();
}
```

And then in command line:

```
javac some.package.your.MainClass.java
java some.package.your.MainClass
```

Comment: I this way is gonna to help. How about mentioning the TestNG class to be executed using a command line argument(using args variable I can invoke). Anyhow thanks for the info. I 'll try and post the result here.